# Keyset does not exist although the PrivateKey is set

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, rsa, x509certificate

I'm trying to sign a message using `CmsSigner` and attaching X509 certificate:

```
public static byte[] Sign(X509Certificate2 certificate, string keyXml)
{
    ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1"), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello"));

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.FromXmlString(keyXml);

    using (certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
    {
        certificate.PrivateKey = rsa;
    }
    var signer = new CmsSigner(certificate);

    signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");
    signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());

    var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, false);
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
    var encodeByteBlock = signedCms.Encode();
    return encodeByteBlock;
}
```

the certificate doesn't have a key (`HasPrivateKey` is `false`) so I set it with the right key generated using OpenSSL:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -x509 -days 7300 -out ca.crt -keyout ca.key.pem -nodes
```

*I convert the ca.key.pem to XML.*

But when `ComputeSignature` is called, this exception is thrown:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Keyset does not
> exist'

Stack trace:

> at
> System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.PkcsUtils.CreateSignerEncodeInfo(CmsSigner
> signer, Boolean silent, SafeCryptProvHandle& hProv)    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.Sign(CmsSigner signer,
> Boolean silent)    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.ComputeSignature(CmsSigner
> signer, Boolean silent)    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.ComputeSignature(CmsSigner
> signer)    at ConsoleTest472.Program.Sign(X509Certificate2
> certificate, String keyXml) in
> D:\me\Projects\ConsoleTest472\ConsoleTest472\Program.cs:line 56    at
> ConsoleTest472.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> D:\me\Projects\ConsoleTest472\ConsoleTest472\Program.cs:line 63

What is wrong with the code I'm using? doesn't the *keyset* is set when the private key is..set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with the code I'm using?

```
using (certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    certificate.PrivateKey = rsa;
}
```

doesn't make much sense.  You're acquiring the private key, then ignoring it, attempting to replace it, then disposing it.

A better version would be

```
var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, false);

using (X509Certificate2 certWithKey = certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa))
{
    var signer = new CmsSigner(certWithKey);

    signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");
    signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());

    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
}

var encodeByteBlock = signedCms.Encode();
return encodeByteBlock;
```

Which does the work of binding the private key to a copy of the certificate (rather than do mutation), and does whatever is necessary to make that work (in this case, it'll end up replacing the RSACryptoServiceProvider key with an RSACng key, because the platform only supports CNG for memory-only (ephemeral) keys).

Comment: I got it that my code doesn't make sense, but when the PrivateKey is set to an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` object and HasPrivateKey is `true`, why it can't find the keyset?

Comment: It can mean "this is a memory-only key, but I need a named key" or "this key only had public key information, but I need the private key", or "hm, this key was supposed to be stored in a file, but the file is missing".  In your case, I think it said "I'm a persisted key named NULL", then the load comes back as "I can't find a key with no name...".  You shouldn't ever use the PrivateKey setter, and should avoid using its getter.

Answer (score 1):

The private key must be either:

- in the `MY` Key Store of the user executing the code
- in the `MY` Key Store of the Machine, with permission granted to the user
- stored together with the certificate in a PFX/PKCS#12 file and loaded as X509Certificate2 with the password protecting it.